# Can I copy-elide an immovable & uncopyable function result into an optional?

Tags: c++, copy-elision, stdoptional

I want to store a *non-trivial* type that is immovable and not copyable in an [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). However the object is constructed by a free function. ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/E7frrcMrf))

```
struct Foo {
    Foo();
    Foo(Foo const&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(Foo const&) = delete; // added for completeness
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = delete; // added for completeness
    ~Foo();
};
Foo foo();
```

Without changing `Foo` or `foo()`;

Thanks to copy elision, I can already do this:

```
Foo f1 = foo();
```

And this also compiles, because `std::optional` only requires the stored type to be destructible:

```
std::optional<Foo> f2;
f2.emplace();
```

But I cannot fill `f2` with a function result:

```
f2 = foo(); // no
f2.emplace(foo()); // no
```

Obviously, because this would require copies or moves of `Foo`. **This is likely impossible, but have I overlooked something?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can make a class where a conversion operator calls the function and returns the result. Since the conversion operator will create a prvalue, you don't need the type to be copyable/movable:

```cpp
template<typename F>
struct call_wrapper {
    F&& f;

    constexpr operator decltype(auto)() && {
        return static_cast<F&&>(f)();
    }
};
template<typename F>
call_wrapper(F&&) -> call_wrapper<F>;


std::optional<Foo> f2;
f2.emplace(call_wrapper{foo});
```

Comment: [Here's a live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j8d7nTvdv). Seems to work well.

Comment: Why `static_cast<F&&>`? Seems to work without it: https://godbolt.org/z/1nKP513q4

Comment: @SolomonUcko Perfect forwarding doesn't hurt. You can imagine a situation where the call needs to be on an rvalue (Like with call_wrapper itself because is meant to only be called once) or maybe an rvalue call is more efficient (`std::move(f)()` stealing from `f`)

Comment: Note that the rules that govern such an elision are not fully specified; [CWG 2327](https://wg21.link/cwg2327)

Comment: I'd use `std::forward<F>(f)()` instead of `static_cast<F&&>(f)()`.  The effect is identical, but it makes it clear you are doing perfect forwarding.  Second, note that this technique doesn't support all types -- the type cannot have a constructor that accepts `call_wrapper<F>`.  This happens for some ill-behaved types, like C++11's std::function (later versions behave better).

Answer (score 15):

We can take advantage of `transform` (new in C++23), which supports guaranteed elision:

```cpp
auto f = std::optional(1).transform([](int) { return foo(); });
```

This is slightly more general than `call_wrapper` because it works even in cases where `Foo` would constructible from `call_wrapper` (because, for instance, it has a converting constructor template that accepts everything).

Comment: Yes, I think this would be the way to go for C++23.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this fits your requirement of not modifying `Foo` or `foo`, but you can use a `Bar` wrapper that default initializes a `Foo` member by calling `foo`:

```
#include <optional>

namespace {
    struct Foo {
        Foo() = default;
        Foo(Foo const&) = delete;
        Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
        Foo& operator=(Foo const&) = delete;
        Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = delete;
        ~Foo() {}
    };
    Foo foo() { return {}; }

    struct Bar {
        Foo f = foo();
    };
}

int main() {
    std::optional<Bar> f3;
    f3.emplace();
}
```

I think the answer to the title is No. You cannot copy or move a `Foo` into an `optional`, but via the wrapper you can construct it in place.