# friend function and allocator_traits in c++ 20

Tags: c++, c++20

I am upgrading my c++14 to c++20 and allocator_traits suddenly stopped working. I am using `friend` for the `construct` method of the allocator_traits because my `custom type A` has a private constructor. I see the deprecation of `construct` of `std::allocator`, would that affect the use of `allocator_traits`? Or the usage of `friend` has been changed?

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1700 // VS2012
   friend void std::allocator<std::_List_node<A,void *>>::construct<A>(A *);
   friend void std::allocator<std::_List_node<A,void *>>::construct<A,const A&>(A *,const A &);
#if _MSC_VER >= 1900 // VS2017
   friend void std::_Default_allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_List_node<A, void *>>>::construct<A>(std::allocator<std::_List_node<A, void *>> &, A *const);
   friend void std::_Default_allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_List_node<A, void *>>>::construct<A, const A&>(std::allocator<std::_List_node<A, void *>> &, A *const, const A &);
#endif // _MSC_VER >= 1900
#endif // _MSC_VER
```

I tried to get rid of the `std::allocator::construct` but then the `allocator_traits` wouldn't work any more.
Since the `std::allocator::construct` has been removed, is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Can we have a [mre] please

Comment: "deprecated" only means that it is in the queue to maybe be removed at some point until then you can still use it. And `friend` didnt change.

Comment: Don't `friend` external functions, they might forward to another functions, breaking your friendship.

Comment: [passkey idiom](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/10/passkey-idiom/) is a good alternative.

Comment: Although the **passkey idiom*" is one of my favorite patterns, the fact that OP has targeted std directs me to a new unnamed pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067846/can-i-copy-elide-an-immovable-uncopyable-function-result-into-an-optional

Answer (score 4):

> I am using `friend` for the `construct` method of the `allocator_traits` because my `custom type A` has a private constructor.

Well that was *never* guaranteed to work. If it worked on one or more implementations, there was never any promise by the standard that the implementation would not change in a way that broke said code.

The problem is that `friend` is not recursive; it only gives permission to that function, not functions that function calls. And the default `std::allocator_traits::construct` implementation does not have to *directly* call the constructor. It could use an intermediary function. And the standard has never promised that it would not.

So you need to create access in a way that *is* recursive, such that one function can pass that access to another. The way to do this is to make the constructor public but change its interface so that it requires a parameter which can only be created privately.

This involves using a key type. A key type is just an empty object whose default constructor is private, but the copy/move constructors are public. If you have an object of that type, you can copy it and pass it to someone else, but only those who have private access to the key can *create* one from scratch.

A reuseable key type would look like this:

```
template<typename Owner>
class key_type
{
public:
  constexpr key_type(key_type const&) = default;

private:
  constexpr key_type() = default; //In pre-C++20, this would still allow using `{}` to create one.

  friend Owner;
};
```

This type automatically gives constructor access to the given class, so it can create them.

So your "custom type `A`" would now have a public constructor, but it would also need a private function to create a key:

```
class A
{
public:
  A(key_type<A>, ...);

private:
  static constexpr key_type<A> unlock() {return key_type<A>();}
};
```

Anyone who has private access to `A` can call `A::unlock`. And therefore, only they can construct them, but they can also pass that access to others.

Comment: Instead of having a private constructor, a key type can also be just forward declared (a incomplete type) if only one factory class needed to create it. In this case, the key type class definition is put in the same file as the factory, and other classes take the key type by reference.

Comment: Nice exposition.  _Anyone who has private access to `A`_ - so would that be a friend of `A`?  (Since we are otherwise in a 'Catch-22' situation.)

Comment: @PaulSanders The trick is that anyone who has private access to `A` *can pass a `key_type` around*, and thus allow someone else to use the key.  For example, `std::shared_ptr<A> make_A_ptr() { return std::make_shared<A>( A::unlock(); } }` -- here, we pass the right to create an `A` to `make_shared` from a context where we can call `A::unlock()` and get a key.  All of this without relying on the (not reliable) friending of `make_shared`.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Hmmm, that [does not compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Fq0shbNCHjurSyt2).  (I'm probably missing something...)

Comment: @PaulSanders: It's not *supposed* to compile. `make_A_ptr` does not have private access to `A`, so it cannot access `A::unlock`. This is precisely what it is meant to prevent. `make_A_ptr` must have private access: it must be a friend or a member. Or the caller of `make_A_ptr` must give it an `key_type<A>`.

Comment: @PaulSanders https://wandbox.org/permlink/dV2QUx7dGTCSPrUP - `make_A_ptr` has to be in a context where it has private-rights to `A`.  It can then get a key object.  This key object in turn can be used to delegate the right-to-construct to `make_shared`.  The key bit here is that `make_shared`, despite not being a friend, is able to construct an `A`.  Meanwhile, if you tried to make an `A` in main, it would fail.

Comment: @yakk OK, understood, thanks.