Can I have a std::optional<T> if T is neither constructible nor copyable nor movable?
The only requirement to type parameter of std::optional<T> class template mentioned in [optional.optional.general] p3 is that type T is Destructible.
Suppose I have a very restrictive class which meets that requirement:
struct R
{
    R(const R&) = delete;
    R& operator=(const R&) = delete;
    R(R&&) = delete;
    R& operator=(R&&) = delete;

    // This works thanks to guaranteed copy elision since C++17.
    static R create()
    {
        return R();
    }

  private:
    R() = default;
};

Yet that class is still perfectly usable:
void test_1()
{
    R obj = R::create();
    /* use obj */
}

The question is: can I really have a usable object of type std::optional<R>? By "usable" I mean an object that contains value. If yes, then how do I construct that value there?
The following code obviously fails because every constructor of R is inaccessible:
void test_2()
{
    std::optional<R> o(R::create());   // Error: no matching constructor
}

Godbolt example link.

Edit:
Wouldn't it be nice if std::optional had a constructor that accepted a builder?
template <typename Builder>
optional::optional(disabmiguating_tag, Builder f)
 : my_internal_union(f())
{
}

with apropriate constructor of my_internal_union of course...

You can use std::optional<R>(std::in_place), which will work if there is an accessible constructor (so you would have to make the default constructor public here). It makes sense that you cannot construct a std::optional<R> from an existing object of type R, if R is not movable.

You are obviously wrong on some level. The class must have a constructor. Otherwise, you'll be able to create the optional type but will never be able to assign anything to it, making it utterly useless for all purposes. You ought to read beyond technicalities and draw conclusions.

@iz_ No you can't, see the standard: optional.ctor.13, which states template<class... Args> constexpr explicit optional(in_place_t, Args&&... args); Constraints: is_constructible_v<T, Args...> is true. And T is just not constructible (with or without args). The std::inplace constructor is an optimization available for classes with constructors (to avoid construction and then move or copy into the optional)

@PepijnKramer Yes you are correct, that is why I mentioned that the default constructor must be made public. Once that is done, std::optional<R>(std::in_place) will work even though std::optional<R>(R()) does not.

@iz_ Ok  Just wanted to make sure. Just being movable is not enough for inplace construction either ;)

There's an old exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067846/can-i-copy-elide-an-immovable-uncopyable-function-result-into-an-optional

This question is similar to: Can I copy-elide an immovable & uncopyable function result into an optional?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can use a a type with an operator R:
struct Builder {
    operator R() const { return R::create(); }
};

int main() {
    std::optional<R> o(Builder{});
}

See live example at Compiler Explorer
This works because the std::optional<R> o is constructed via the constructor #8 on cppreference, which means that the R that inhabits o is constructed as if by calling
R(std::move(builder))

... where builder is a reference to the Builder{} we have passed in.
operator R returns a prvalue, so the returned R::create() and the constructed R are the same object, by virtue of C++17 guaranteed copy elision.

What a clever trick!

Interesting, this bypasses all the filters imposed by the other constructor of optional. This seems accidental, if, for example, optional had a constructor that takes R by value (there is no reason for not having one) this trick wouldn’t be necessary?

@alfC this wouldn't work because std::optional would need to move from the R that it receives in the constructor as a paremeter object into the object it stores internally. However, R is immovable. Also, there are other good reasons against taking things by value, which is why the standard library takes almost every user type by reference.

@JanSchultke, I've added a details which I think slightly improve the text. The R could have been the one returned by operator R, and I've specified is the one inside o. Yes, they are exactly the same thing, but that's written later. As regards the mention of copy elision. Is that it, or am I mistaken? Obviously feel free to undo if you think I made it worse.

@Enlico you're basically right; most people know this effect as "guaranteed copy elision", though the term is slightly informal and not used in the standard. Still, putting it here improves searchability of the answer.

I know the question is c++17, but apparently c++23 you can use this trick:
auto o = std::optional<int>{0}.transform([](int){ return R::create(); });

where we create a dummy non-empty optional (in this case std::optional<int>) and use std::optional<T>::transform to apply a function on its inner int; that function returns the desired R object via R::create(), which is created in place in the memory that std::optional keeps reserved for its payload.
It is valid because of C++17's mandatory copy elision, because the lambda return type is R, which is the same type as R::create(), which in turn is prvalue. I think that means that this R object is constructed directly in the "final" place, which is inside the std::optional<R> o that you are constructing.

Probably std::construct_at from c++20 is the core of the trick, but I don't think you can use it from the outside, because you don't have access to std::optional's member where the payload is stored, and you can't access to it via .value() because that's UB on an empty std::optional, and you can't have a non-empty std::optional<R> because that's precisely what we are discussing!

Why do you say you can't access .value()?

@alfC, to access .value() of a std::optional<R>, you need a non-empty std::optional<R> to start with. And that's what we are trying to construct in the first place, no? To clarify, I was wondering if one could use std::construct_at to make up a std::optional<R>, and I think one cannot, because you can't get a pointer to the R if the std::optional is empty.
